# pass multiple dictionaries to a get request in flask

Tags: python, parsing, flask, python-requests, get-request

I would like to pass multiple arguments in a GET request. Normally one would enlist the args as:

```
http://localhost:5010/my_query=get_foo&A=5&B=6&C=10
```

However, I wish to send something like this:

```
d1={'id':1, 'A':5,'B':6,'C':10} 
d2={'id':2, 'A':1,'B':0,'C':7}
```

Question, how can I pass multiple dictionaries in a GET request and later parse them as:

```
def get_foo(kwargs):    
      
    
    d1 = kwargs.get("d1")
    d2 = kwargs.get("d2")
     
    #parse d1 to dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

url encode it, but i would recommend to create a post endpoint instead of get, the data u send isn't encrypted

```py
import urllib.parse
"d1=" + urllib.parse.quote_plus("{'id':1, 'A':5,'B':6,'C':10}")
# 'd1=%7B%27id%27%3A1%2C+%27A%27%3A5%2C%27B%27%3A6%2C%27C%27%3A10%7D'
```

Comment: thanks; how would you convert the d1 back to a dictionary (I thought json.load would do the trick)

Comment: indeed json.loads, you pass strings in url anyway